# Linux. Different backup drive each week to same mount point

Tags: linux, mount

We have an external drive that our server backs up to nightly. It is mounted to /snapshots. We are planning to swap this disk out each week. The problem is that one drive comes up as /dev/sdc and the other as /dev/sdd. In the fstab the mount is set to /dev/sdc. Before backing up a scripts runs to mount /snapshots which gets its mount point from fstab.

How can I get it to mount /dev/sdc one week and /dev/sdd the next week. It has to be automatic as the people who swap the disk over will not be going into the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one crontab for every week `0 2 * * 2 /usr/local/script.sh` and put in `script.sh` :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mark_file=/tmp/job-run-marker
# check whether the job runned last week
if [ -e $mark_file ] ; then
  rm -f $mark_file
  unmout /snapshots
  mount /dev/disk/by-label/even-weeks /snapshots
else
  touch $mark_file
  unmout /snapshots
  mount /dev/disk/by-label/odd-weeks /snapshots
fi
```

The script will not find `$mark_file` on the first run, so it will mount `/dev/disk/by-label/even-weeks`. On the second run the script will remove `$mark_file` and then mount `/dev/disk/by-label/odd-weeks`. For the third run, it is the same as the first run. So if this script is run weekly by cron, the job command will run every two weeks.

Tips : Label your disk `ln -s /dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID /dev/disk/by-label/even-weeks`

EDIT :

- Correction after the comment @Mat.
- From the comment of @nearora : Label yours filesystems with links to /dev/disk/by-id/ instead of use /dev/sd[a-z].

Comment: You'll need to exit in the `sdc` case or pull the `sdd` case in the `if` branch, otherwise you'll be doing mount sdc, unmount, mount sdd.

Comment: Instead of using /dev/sd[a-z] use links in /dev/disks/by-id/. Give your ext2/3 filesystems a label and they'll show up there!

Answer (score 0):

When I do this type of backup script, I just mount whichever of my backup disks is attached at the time. Obviously they are labelled BackupDisk1, BackupDisk2...

```
if mount /dev/disk/by-label/BackupDisk* /snapshots
then
    # rest of backup script goes here
else
    logmsg "Unable to mount external drive."
fi
```

This way, the timing of the disk swap is not critical and the script can't get "out of sync" with the disk being used.